# How to configure a read-only relationship using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a question about how to configure a Many to Many relationship using SQAlchemy avoiding to cascade any operation to a read-only table. Here the example:

#### Secondary table to be used on a Many to Many relationship

```
map_setores_funcionalidades = db.Table("map_setores_funcionalidades",
    Column("id_setor", Integer, ForeignKey("setores.id")),
    Column("id_funcionalidade", Integer, ForeignKey("dominios.dm_funcionalidade.id")))
```

#### Main class

```
class Setor(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "setores"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    uuid = Column(String(36), unique=True, nullable=False, default=uuid4)
    nome = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    
    funcionalidades = relationship(Funcionalidade, secondary=map_setores_funcionalidades, lazy="select")
```

My problem occours when I receive a new 'Setor' object from my REST service to be persisted in database (so the whole object is not managed by the SQAlchemy), then some SQL Insert operations are created, the insert for the table 'setores' (Ok) and a second one for the table 'dominios.dm_funcionalidade' (I'd like to avoid this) for each object inside the List  'funcionalidades'.

It works only if I get all 'funcionalidades' objects from database first, then update the managed object to my 'Setor' and then persist, but I think it's an unnecessary overhead since I could just tell to SQLAlchemy that 'dominios.funcionalidade' Table is a read-only relationship.

So, what I would like to do:

1. Persist 'Setor' object;
2. Persist the secondary table 'map_setores_funcionalidades' with the mapping info;
3. Do nothig to 'dominios.dm_funcionalidade' table;

P.S.: My database user has only a read permission on 'dominios' database schema.

I hope I made my self clear. I tried to find something about it, using relationship properties like, cascade=False or viewonly=True, but none worked for me. Maybe something to configure the *ForeignKey("dominios.dm_funcionalidade.id")* making it read-only, avoiding all cascade operations to the table 'domninios.dm_funcionalidade'....